# python "class" word promblem

Tags: python, class, object

The question reads

Write a class named Car that has the following data attributes:

`__year_model`( for the car’s year model)

`__make`(for the car’s make of the car)

`__speed`( for the car’s current speed)

The Car class should have a `__init__` method that accepts the car’s year model and make as arguments. It should also assign 0 to the `__speed` data attribute.

The class should also have the following methods:

•   Accelerate
The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed data attribute each time it is called.

•   Brake
The brake method should subtract 5 from the speed data attribute each time it is called.

•   The get_speed
The get_speed method should return the current speed

Next, Design a program that creates a car object, and then calls the accelerate method five times. After each call to the accelerate method, get the current speed of the car and display it. Then call the brake method five times. After each call to the brake method, get the current speed of the car and display it.

I'm getting error `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'year', 'make', and 'speed'`

my code:

```
#create class called car

class Car:
    def __init__(self,year,make,speed):
        self.__year_model=year
        self.__make=make
        self.__speed=0

    #set the arguments for speed,year, and make
    def set_year_model(self,year):
        self.__year_model=year

    def set_make(self,make):
        self.__make=make

    def set_speed(self,speed):
        self.__speed=0

    #the returns for speed, year, and make
    def get_year_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed


    #methods
    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed +=5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed-=5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

#actuall program
#create car object
def main():
    my_car=Car()

    year=print(input('car year: '))
    make=print(input('car make: '))
    speed= print('Current speed is 0')

    #accelerate 5 times

    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())

    #brake five times
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())

main()
```

Comment: Is the course you're on actually a Python course? All those `get_` and `set_` are not necessary... In fact, it's a rather horrible introduction to using classes in Python...

Comment: Furthermore, the double-underscore attributes are also really bad form.  If you don't know why you specifically need them, you shouldn't be using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. You've defined `Car` to need three parameters:

```
def __init__(self, year, make, speed):
```

But when you create one, you don't pass any of those:

```
my_car = Car()
```

See? Nothing in the parentheses.  Obviously this needs to be:

```
my_car = Car(year, make, speed)
```

Now of course, you can't do that because you haven't asked for these items yet. So create `my_car` *after* getting that information from the user.

Comment: Yes, there are other problems with your code... for example, you have a `print` in front of all your `input`s.... and now apparently you've put `int` in there but forgot to close the parenthesis (so you're not actually running the code you posted) but that has nothing do do with the question you asked.

Comment: how can i remove the "none" that is being printed?

Comment: also im getting AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'speed'

Comment: That latter error is because the attribute is named `__speed` when you create it, but you try to access it as `speed` in some places. Obviously you need to use the same name everywhere. (I'd recommend just getting rid of the getter and setter methods; Python is not Java.)

Comment: It's because you're doing e.g. `year = print(input(...))`. `print` returns `None` so that is what you are assigning to `year`. Therefore all those values are `None`. I'm not sure what you think putting that `print` in there is doing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__` for the `Car` class takes three arguments you are not passing any.

```
year=input('car year: '))
make=input('car make: '))
speed=0
print'Current speed is', speed
#actuall program
#create car object
def main():
my_car=Car(year, make, speed)
```

You don't need those `print` statements before the `input`. I'm not sure what you are tying to do with that. Also `speed= print('Current speed is 0')` is not correct.

This function always sets the speed back to zero, if that is what you intend then there is no need to pass the argument `speed`. Same thing with your init, there is no need to pass an argument if you are nor using it.

```
def set_speed(self,speed):
    self.__speed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

class Car(object): # made class called car
    def **init**(self, model, make): 
    self.__model = model
    self.__make = make
    self.__speed = 0
    def accelerate(self):
    self.__speed += 5 #increase 5 speed
    def brake(self):
    self.__speed -= 5 #decrease 5 speed

```
def get_speed(self):
return self.__speed #return speed

wr_handle = open("output_04.txt", "w+")
carObject = Car( 1984,"Chevron")
wr_handle.write("Car is accelerating: \n")
print("Car is accelerating:") #accelerate 5 times
for p in range(0, 5):
carObject.accelerate()
my_car_speed = carObject.get_speed()
wr_handle.write("The current speed is: %d \n"% my_car_speed)
print("The current speed is: %d "% my_car_speed)

wr_handle.write("Car is braking: \n")
print("Car is braking: ") #brake 5 times
for p in range(0,5):
carObject.brake()
my_car_speed = carObject.get_speed()
wr_handle.write("The current speed is: %d \n"% my_car_speed)
print("The current speed is: %d "% my_car_speed)

wr_handle.write("Bye! \n")
print("Bye! ")
wr_handle.close()
```

Comment: This code runs but you will get a indent error because stack overflow wasn't letting me post without keeping everything in one way.

Comment: class Car(object): # made class called car
    def __init__(self, model, make): 
        self.__model = model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0
    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5 #increase 5 speed
        
    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5 #decrease 5 speed

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Intendation is important in python, a code with wrong indentation is wrong. Copy paste your code in the answer, select it and click on `{}` in the top bar to get the proper format. Also, try to elaborate the answer with a bit of explanation rather than just providing a code. It will improve the quality of the answer. Stackowerflow is not a free coding service, you should try to explain why your code works.

Answer (score -1):

class Car(object): # made class called car
    def **init**(self, model, make): 
        self.__model = model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0
    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5 #increase 5 speed

```
def brake(self):
    self.__speed -= 5 #decrease 5 speed
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.